# cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation - npm not working in ios 10

Tags: cordova, geolocation, phonegap-build, ios10

I have been using this plugin from last 2 months. It was working fine in android and ios but to my surprise it stopped working in ios 10 and the issue is when I close the app, app is showing permission pop ups but since there are more than 3 permission pop ups, it gets overriding each other. So the background geo is not able to start the tracking.

I am using phone gap build to generate the build for both android and Iphone.

Comment: I have same problem did you fix it